# What does こんな mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

Please allow to establish the context.

There is 1990 roleplaying video game titled “Illumina!” (Japanese title: イルミナ!), which is one of Cocktail Soft's products.

In the game, there is an evil necromancer named Rasuneti (Japanese name: ラスネティ). As the game goes on, she becomes a threat to the protagonist. Their confrontation finally ends with the protagonist running his sword through her heart. At that point, she says the following:

> ば…ばかな…私が…こんな…

I think the translation goes something like this:

> Ab...absurd...I am...like this...

I know that こんな usually means “such” or “like this”, but when I see the word being used like this in Japanese media, I keep getting the feeling that it is being used to mean something else.

Am I on the right track? What does it mean in that context?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I think when used like that there is usually something not said, like in this case it could be `こんなことあり得ない`, "It's not possible something like this [to be defeated by the hero]", or `私がこんなふうに殺された`, "Ab... absurd... me being killed like this...".

Comment: Oh, thank you! I knew that there was something being omitted in that sentence! I guess I just needed some help in filling in the blanks. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: By 無理だ you meant "this is impossible"? Perhaps you wanted to say こんなこと(は)あり得ない. こんなこと無理だ usually means "I can never do this".

Comment: Yes, thanks; I edited my answer.